# Bad Request when fetching id token from Google

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-api, fetch, token

This may be a newbiew question (I haven't used the `fetch` api before), but I can't figure out what wrong with my request.

```
fetch('https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?key=' + API_KEY, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
  body: 'grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=' + refreshToken
})
.then(response => console.log(response))
.catch(error => console.error(error))
```

I'm trying to exchange a refresh token for an id token following the guidelines [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-refresh-token), but for some reason I'm getting a `Bad Request` response...

```
Response { type: "cors", url: "https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?key=[API_KEY]", redirected: false, status: 400, ok: false, statusText: "Bad Request", headers: Headers, body: ReadableStream, bodyUsed: false }
```

My `key` is correct, and the `refreshToken` is also straight from a response from a service on Firebase SDK.

Where exactly is my mistake?

**UPDATE**

1. Showing the context where fetch is executed in a Next.js app:
2. I'm running this code in dev (localhost) using Firebase Emulators.
3. I managed to find additional error logs that state `{ code: 400, message: "INVALID_REFRESH_TOKEN", status: "INVALID_ARGUMENT" }`.

So, this indeed seems to be an issue with the refresh_token. Can it be because it has been emitted by Firebase Emulators?

```
useEffect(() => {

  return firebase.auth().onIdTokenChanged(async user => {

    if (user) {

      fetch('https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?key=' + process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        body: 'grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=' + user.refreshToken
      })
      .then(response => console.log(response))
      .catch(error => console.error(error))
    }
  })
}, [])
```

Comment: What seems strange at first sight is that the error returns `url: "https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?key=API_KEY"` instead of `url: "https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?key=[THE_REAL_API_KEY_VALUE]"`. Did you change it yourself before writing the question?

Comment: Sorry, it's just me editing the real key out like this... Changed it to `[API_KEY]` now to make it clearer.

Comment: "the refreshToken is also straight from a response from a service on Firebase SDK." => Can you give more details? Which exact SDK method do you call?

Comment: `firabase.auth().onIdTokenChanged(user => { const {refreshToken} = user })`

Comment: It should work... I've tried your code and it works in my own "environment" (a simple HTML page stored locally).

Comment: Can you show your entire code? I.E. the `onIdTokenChanged` part with the `fetch` part? To see how they are "coupled".

Comment: I updated my question with more context. I'm calling `onIdTokenChanged` inside a `useEffect` in a `React` app.

Comment: I don't see where there can be an error... sorry. (just one side remark: if you use `async`, you should use `await` with fetch. However this is not the cause of the problem)

Comment: Erm... just one quick clarification. Could it be because I'm running this code on dev (localhost) using Firebase Emulators?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237169/discussion-between-artooras-and-renaud-tarnec).

Comment: Yes it could very well be the reason

Answer (score 0):

In the end the cause for the issue was the fact that the `refreshToken` issued when using `Firebase Emulators` is not valid when exchanging for an idToken.

Quite an edge case, but perhaps someone may find this helpful.